# How to detect push notification event and message from device console

Tags: ios, logging, push-notification

I need to do some bulk testing for push to detect what is the typical success rate and delay for notifications to reach device.
I wrote a server code that send notifications to a device in a time interval and later on I want to check the notifications in device console. Is there any way to look into push message and timestamp in console? i.e. what message I should look for to detect the event?

I am following the process described http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html

anybody followed the same? There are so many apsd name event in the log location!

Answer (score 1):

If the log is verbose, pipe the `tail` and `grep` tools to only see the event you are interested in:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep "Received message for enabled topic"
```